# Thread in Spring initializing Hibernate connection pool at first usage (id=1 not persisted)

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How can I overcome it? I have a @Service that implements Runnable and it's using a JPA Repository. The connection to the db is established upon the first persist, not before, resulting in id=1 not being persisted...

Any thoughts?

```
Thread u = new Thread(service);
        u.start();
        u.join();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'a @Service that implements Runnable'? How are you running the service?

Comment: @crizzis Added it to my question

Comment: OK, in that case the answer is you should never **ever** manually run a service method dealing with persistence on a different thread than the one the injecting service method is running. See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

Comment: Ok, so how can I inject my repository / entityManager to the service in question? @crizzis

Comment: Not sure why that would be a problem, because you haven't posted the actual surrounding code, but in any case, you should put `@Async @Transactional` on the `run` method and simply call it from another bean

Comment: The problem is exactly how I stated it in my question:the Thread creates its own Hibernate connection pool after the first persist. It's all right with me, but how to control it to initialize earlier? @crizzis

Comment: If the question is 'how do I control undefined behaviour?', the answer is nobody is going to give you an authoritative answer, I'm afraid